# Is this a Swing Java 7 rendering bug?

Tags: java, swing, java-7

I made a simple Swing application. But the rendering behaves buggy. Have I done anything wrong or is it a bug?

It's simple a small JFrame with a textfield, button and an empty list. If I first resizes the window horizontally and then type in the textfield, the button suddenly disappear.

Here is my code:

```
public class App extends JFrame {

    public App() {

        JTextField messageFld = new JTextField();
        JButton saveBtn = new JButton("Save");

        JPanel inputPanel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        inputPanel.add(messageFld, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        inputPanel.add(saveBtn, BorderLayout.EAST);

        JList<Data> list = new JList<Data>();
        JPanel panel = new JPanel(new BorderLayout());
        panel.add(inputPanel, BorderLayout.NORTH);
        panel.add(list, BorderLayout.CENTER);

        this.getContentPane().add(panel);
        this.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        this.setTitle("Test application");
        this.pack();
        this.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new App();
            }
        });
    }

}
```

Here are a few screenshots:

1. **At start up**

   [image]
2. **After horizontal resize**

   [image]
3. **After typig a few charachers in the textfield**

   [image]
4. **After moving the mouse over the button**

   [image]

I use Windows 7, Java 1.7.0 and Eclipse Indigo SR1.
I used JDK 1.7.0.0 and have now upgraded to JDK 1.7.0.10 but I still have the same problem.

When I print the system properties I get this result:

```
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.version"));
System.out.println(System.getProperty("java.runtime.version"));

> 1.7.0_01
> 1.7.0_01-b08
```

Comment: weird, can't reproduce (jdk7, vista)

Comment: I also use jdk 1.7.0 and Windows 7 and the "Save" button is always displayed correctly.

Comment: unable to reproduce with Eclipse Juno and Java 1.7.0-b147, also tried different L&F (Nimbus, Metal, Motif, Windows)

Comment: It's probably a bug from the graphics driver.  I have an ATI card and no bug.

Comment: +1, it's a bug, for `BorderLayout.EAST`  or `BorderLayout.LINE_END`. Placing the component at any other place, won't lead to the problem. So seems like that area is buggy :-)

Comment: Exactly the same issue I am facing with JRE 1.7 update 3, as described in [My Question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9849950/1057230)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In case the issue is caused by your graphics driver, setting one of the system properties below could help. Not quite sure if the props are still supported in Java 7.

```
sun.java2d.d3d=false
sun.java2d.ddoffscreen=false
sun.java2d.noddraw=true
```

Comment: This solved this specific problem. But I got similar issues again when adding more components.

Comment: Setting -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false for my JVM startup options cleared out a lot of rendering bugs for me: JDK7/Windows7.

Comment: @wzberger same issue is now occurring for table components  in jdk 1.8 update 31 and 40, tried setting up your suggested system properties but still not working, issue is similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28876538/java-swing-component-rendering-issue-with-java-8-update-31?noredirect=1#comment46015550_28876538

Answer (score 1):

I am using eclipse helios service release 2, and java 1.6 and I am not getting that bug; it works fine for me. However it wont let me add parameters to JList...that may be because I'm using an older version of java...so basically with my setup and no parameters for JList it works...I'm not sure if this will help you, but those are my observations

Comment: I got the same 'null result' also using Java 1.6.  I suspect the OP is best off posting an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) that starts the GUI on the EDT and dumps some basic Java version properties to the `System.out`.